# update datatable vb.net to mysql with update command and is very slow

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable

Im using VB.net and i Try to update from DataTable changes to a database in MySql, thats is ok, it works but is very slowly!!

**Details**

The Datatable is called "listado"

When i found a change, i need put into another Datatable the changes are made, I can see that is the very slow part

**question**

Is very slow, about 15 minutes. 
What is the best way to do this?

**The code**

```
Using conexiontemporal As New MySqlConnection(conexionstring)   
        Dim sql As String
        Dim cm As MySqlCommand
        Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
        sql = "SELECT id, nombre, (SELECT nombre FROM categoriadeproductos WHERE id = categoria) AS categoria , cantidad, stockminimo, precio, precio2, costo, ganancia,  fecha, codigobarras FROM productos WHERE promocionid = 0 AND eliminado = 0"' AND (nombre LIKE '%"& filtro &"%')"& cate & orden
        cm = New MySqlCommand()
        cm.CommandText = sql
        cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cm.Connection = conexiontemporal        
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cm)
        Dim actualiza As MySqlCommand
        actualiza = New MySqlCommand()
        actualiza.Connection = conexiontemporal
        actualiza.CommandText="INSERT INTO movimientostock (idproducto, razondemovimiento, cantidad, dineroanterior) Select @idnueva, 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO COSTO', @costonueva, (Select costo from productos where id = @idnueva) WHERE @costonueva <> (Select costo from productos where id = @idnueva) ;" & _
            "           INSERT INTO movimientostock (idproducto, razondemovimiento, cantidad, dineroanterior) Select @idnueva, 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO FRACCIONARIO', @precio2nueva, (Select precio2 from productos where id = @idnueva) WHERE @precio2nueva <> (Select precio2 from productos where id = @idnueva) ;" & _
            "           INSERT INTO movimientostock (idproducto, razondemovimiento, cantidad, dineroanterior) Select @idnueva, 'DINERO', @precionueva, (Select precio from productos where id = @idnueva) WHERE @precionueva <> (Select precio from productos where id = @idnueva) ;" & _
            "           INSERT INTO movimientostock (idproducto, razondemovimiento, cantidad, dineroanterior) Select @idnueva, 'CAMBIO DE GANANCIA', @ganancianueva, (Select ganancia from productos where id = @idnueva) WHERE @ganancianueva <> (Select ganancia from productos where id = @idnueva) ;" & _
            "           INSERT INTO movimientostock (idproducto, razondemovimiento, cantidad, dineroanterior) Select @idnueva, 'ENTRADA', (@cantidadnueva - (Select cantidad from productos where id = @idnueva)), (Select precio from productos where id = @idnueva) * (@cantidadnueva - (Select cantidad from productos where id = @idnueva)) WHERE @cantidadnueva > (Select cantidad from productos where id = @idnueva);" & _
            "           INSERT INTO movimientostock (idproducto, razondemovimiento, cantidad, dineroanterior) Select @idnueva, 'SALIDA', ((Select cantidad from productos where id = @idnueva) - @cantidadnueva), - ((Select precio from productos where id = @idnueva) * ((Select cantidad from productos where id = @idnueva) - @cantidadnueva)) WHERE @cantidadnueva < (Select cantidad from productos where id = @idnueva) ;" & _
            "           UPDATE productos Set categoria = (Select id FROM categoriadeproductos WHERE nombre = @nombrecategoria), cantidad = @cantidadnueva, " & _
            "           stockminimo = @stockminimonueva, precio = @precionueva, precio2 = @precio2nueva, costo = @costonueva, ganancia = @ganancianueva, codigobarras = @codigobarrasnueva, ultimamodificacion = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = @idnueva;"        
        actualiza.Parameters.Add("stockminimonueva", MySqlDbType.Decimal,10.2,"stockminimo")
        actualiza.Parameters.Add("cantidadnueva", MySqlDbType.Decimal,10.2,"cantidad")
        actualiza.Parameters.Add("precionueva", MySqlDbType.Decimal,10.2,"precio")
        actualiza.Parameters.Add("precio2nueva", MySqlDbType.Decimal,10.2,"precio2")
        actualiza.Parameters.Add("costonueva", MySqlDbType.Decimal,10.2,"costo")
        actualiza.Parameters.Add("ganancianueva", MySqlDbType.Decimal,10.2,"ganancia")
        actualiza.Parameters.Add("idnueva", MySqlDbType.Int32,11,"Id")
        actualiza.Parameters.Add("nombrecategoria", MySqlDbType.Text,0,"categoria")
        actualiza.Parameters.Add("codigobarrasnueva", MySqlDbType.VarChar,50,"codigobarras")
        da.UpdateCommand = actualiza
        'Dim actualiza As MySqlCommandBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)     
        da.Update(listado)
        cm.Dispose
        da.Dispose
    End Using
```

Thanks!

Comment: But you are doing a lot more than just updating.  You are running at least 2 queries per field.  Doesnt seem very maintainable either

Comment: i use two commands, but it works!! if i try to do that only for one query per field, the result are the same! very slow!